# ie9 border radius

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have the following which works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But not in IE9. It's applying rounded corners to the top left and right of a td. What am I missing?

```
border-left: solid 1px #444f82;
border-right:solid 1px #444f82;
border-top:solid 1px #444f82;
border-top-right-radius: 7px;
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
-khtml-border-radius-topright: 7px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
-khtml-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
behavior: url(/survey_templates/PIE.htc);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you got this at the top of your HTML document (Above the `<html>` tag)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

IE9 requires this for the website to display the new HTML5 / CSS3 things

Edit: Or many other Doctype's (XHTML etc, but this is the shortest and easiest to remember)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 75):

As far as I know border radius should work on IE9. You might be missing this in your page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

"edge" means "use the latest rendering engine" so IE 9 will use 9, 10 uses 10, etc.

Comment: that fixed it - hope it doesn't break anything else

Comment: Unbelievable. Adding this just fixed all my IE9 rendering errors. Now looks exactly like WebKit with no CSS changes at all.

Comment: thank you thank you for this! only wish I had found this answer hours ago :}

Comment: As far as I'm aware (and please prove me wrong if there are edge cases) but this is un-necessary if you provide a valid and modern doctype. Isn't it better practice to provide a doctype then add a(nother) line which is IE-specific?

Comment: @Dotmister: that sounds great, assuming you'd care to share an example of what you mean exactly by "valid and modern".  Being 56 years old as I am, to me the pushbutton phone dial is "modern", since I grew up with the old rotary kind. :)

Comment: I don't know why but my `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` was not good enough for IE9, which was in IE7 Standards mode until I also added this meta tag.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Dotmister: Depending on the browser settings the DOCTYPE is not enough to throw IE9 out of compatibility mode. The edge statement ensures it.

Comment: i added this and it still doesn't work! and i have the <!DOCTYPE html> tag! what the hell is wrong??

Answer (score 13):

In addition to causes mentioned by other answers, **Check** in developer's tool (Press<kbd>F12</kbd>) your Document Mode should be set to `Internet Explorer 9 Standards`

[image]

Comment: It said IE 7 standards for Document

Comment: that's the problem change it to IE9 Standards and it should work fine.

Comment: quirks mode: my CSS menu ok, no border-radius. IE9 std: my CSS menu crashes

Comment: Every time I open the developer tools and see 'IE *version* Standards' I want to vomit. As if IE even knows what standards are ;)

Comment: Modifying settings on the viewing client is not a solution to web development problems. You can't know what settings clients are going to have.

Answer (score 1):

Working great in explorer 9 and 8 with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have added `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in the page header and it has resolved my issue.
If border-radius is not working in IE9, you've got to add both `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in the page header.
Please bear in mind if you have `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`
at the top your page the border-radius may not yet appear in IE9, therefore it's better you change it to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: The answer seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that the codes became invisible after inserting them, I have corrected them.