# No Effect using "border-radius" in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css, cornerradius

I Googled this but couldn't find a solution. I'm applying corner-radius to my divs but IE9 doesn't show the effect.

CSS:

```
.ipleft {
width: 512px;
height:300px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
background-image: url(images/ipleft.png);
float: left;}

.ipright {
width: 512px;
position: relative;
height:300px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
-khtml-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
background-image: url(images/ipright.png);
float: right;}
```

I added the appropriate meta tag and it's still not working! The site is www.campusonsale.com. If you take a look with FF the rounded corners are applied without a problem, but IE9 is showing rectangular corners!

Comment: take a look at css3pie.com It's progressive internet explorer, you can use newer css techniques with IE using an htc file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ie9 border radius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381446/ie9-border-radius) -- you probably need to add the right doctype to your HTML file.

Comment: @James the new IE9 supports border-radius so this should work

Answer (score 4):

Your website is being displayed in quirks mode. This is because you have some content (`<script>` element) before `<!doctype>`. In quirks mode, IE uses rendering similar to IE5 and thus `border-radius` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I could be that you need to add this meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

This will tell IE to use the latest rendering engine available to it, meaning the border-radius should render. This only applies to IE9 and later, of course.

Answer (score 0):

IE switches to quirks mode on your page and that's why corners does not work. I think it's because script tag before doctype, but you should use validator to eliminate all possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this. it worked for me:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Comment: Another reason why IE sucks hard.