# Border Radius Not WORKING in IE9

Tags: html, css

Border Radius is not working in IE9. The following Attribute i used in my project. and also i add the .HTC file also

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
behavior: url(Styles/border-radius.htc);
```

Comment: radius at IE is working, mabye somting is wrong with the code can you upload it you can use: PasteBin or anyother site to upload the code, have a nice day.

Comment: The HTC is irrelevent for IE9; you only need it for IE8 or lower. IE9 supports `border-radius` just fine. Don't know why it's not working for you; there's not enough info in the question to diagnose it. You'll need to provide a demonstration of the problem actually happening. One point though: If you are going to use a HTC to support IE7/8, you should consider [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/); it's better than the one you're using.

Comment: IE9 supports border-radius property, once check your browser mode i.e.Browser mode:IE9 and Document mode:IE9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.myclass {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
}
```

IE9 will use the default border-radius, so just make sure you include that in all your styles calling a border radius. Then your site will be ready for IE9.

```
-moz-border-radius is for Firefox, -webkit-border-radius is for Safari and Chrome.
```

Furthermore: don't forget to declare your IE coding is ie9:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Some lazy developers have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`. If that tag exists, border-radius will never work in IE.

Comment: `-moz-` prefix is only for [firefox 3.6 and lower](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius), you may not write it in nowadays

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but it did not help me. My solution was to add the HTML 5 doctype declaration to the page:

<!DOCTYPE html>

Other HTML doctype declarations may work too - my problem was I was generating the pages with no doctype declaration at all.

Comment: I experienced the same problem as the OP;  styles such as `border-radius` and others would not work in Internet Explorer 11, but would work in other browsers such as Firefox.  Adding the `<!DOCTYPE html>`  declaration did help some styles to begin working in IE11.  But the `border-radius` still did not work.

Comment: Follow up:  I experienced the same problem as the OP, but **only** when `border-radius` is defined in an internal style sheet (i.e., within the `<style>` tag in the `<head>`).  In contrast, if I define `border-radius` in an external style sheet (i.e., use `<link>` tag in the `<head>` to include the .css file), then it works without the need for the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration.   Color me perplexed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this in your HTML header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer discovered here [ie9 border radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381446/ie9-border-radius)

Comment: I experienced the same problem as the OP;  styles such as `border-radius` and others would not work in Internet Explorer 11, but would work in other browsers such as Firefox.  Adding the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` tag suggested by @dockeryZ did help the `border-radius` style to work.  That meta tag seems to be the essential thing for `border-radius`.  As I mentioned in another comment, the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration suggested by @Ags1 did not help for `border-radius`, although it did help for other styles.

Comment: Follow up:  I experienced the same problem as the OP, but **only** when `border-radius` is defined in an internal style sheet (i.e., within the `<style>` tag in the `<head>`).  In contrast, if I define `border-radius` in an external style sheet (i.e., use `<link>` tag in the `<head>` to include the .css file), then it works without the need for the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` tag.   Color me perplexed again!

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius.htc` broke normal border-radius in ie9, include border-radius.htc file in ie versions below 9 with `conditional comments`

Answer (score 0):

in IE9 border-radius works without any behavior files.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will also help with lower versions of ie, like ie6,7,8.

Using CSS Pie -> http://css3pie.com/

This will allow you to specify your border radius normally and then include the pie.htc script in your css. This magically make it work in IE6. Look at that!

This also works with other CSS3 properties like background gradients.

You can also try adding this to your head ->

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

border radius supported ie-7, ie-8, ie-9 via javascript 
check this tutorial how to show border radius in ie
http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners

Answer (score 0):

If you use at the same time border-radius with
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='######', endColorstr='######',GradientType=0 ),
just comment this filter.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you include or what you write border-radius doesn't work in ie9. Changing the browser mode or document mode is never a solution because that it is on the client side. So i am afraid my friend there is no plausible way to make border-radius work properly in ie9 unless you take the help of javascript.