# Rounded corners are not working in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ie9 border radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381446/ie9-border-radius)

Rounded corners are not working for me in IE9.

Here is my CSS:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
```

Why are they not working?

Comment: you'd need to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) reproducing this problem. The CSS may be correct, but your html and js also may be not as good as what you think. Also, do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Nope. The code is clean. And it is working well on Chrome and firefox !