# IE9 table not recognize border-radius

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a table and need to set border-radius 5px. It is working perfect in FF and Chrome but not working on IE9.

```
.XYZ table {
  border: 2px solid #E6E7E8;
  border-radius: 0.7em 0.7em 0.7em 0.7em;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381446/ie9-border-radius

Comment: try http://www.css3.me

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: I am working in Drupal and I have added the same tag that you have provided but it's not working in IE9.